# Pushbutton requires two clicks to register click

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

In our Project written in QT, we have multiple widgets. The first one is "login", and after successful log in, the "login" widget closes and create a "main menu" widget. "Main menu" widget has 5 push buttons that represent menu options and clicking each closes the "main menu" widget and create a new widget. The new widget has "back" pushbutton which essentially recreates "main menu" widget when clicked. The problem is when user clicks "back" and "main menu" widget is created, any of the pushbuttons on "main menu" needs to be click twice to register click.  I tried setfocus on "main menu" widget and it didn't work. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: are you destroying main widget? how do you restore the state of the buttons?

Comment: yes I destroy the main widget and create a new one.

Comment: Ok I found something interesting. If I don't delete the main widget, it fixes the problem. If I do, the problem persists.

Comment: yes, you can just hide it or make a different layout for all the widgets, otherwise you will have these problems, because you have to restore the state of one widget based on what is happening in another one.